# Looking for GmailThread.moveToCustomLabel() - Moving thread from Inbox to Custom Label

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-inbox

Per [Google Thread API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread)

there are methods to move a thread to Archive,Inbox,Spam,Trash. However, I would like to move a thread from Inbox to a custom label created by me. Is there a way to achieve this with Google App API ?

Thanks

Comment: I think as of now, it is not possible, but you can move a GmailThread to a customLabel using addLabel but still that thread is still exist in your inbox. The only way that I think to achieve this is only by dragging that message to your created custom label.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [addLabel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#addLabel(GmailLabel)) method?

Comment: if you use that addLabel, it will only add label to the message not move.

Comment: Try this: after adding the label, perform a second operation to remove the 'Inbox' label.

Answer (score 0):

```
let billsLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Bills");
if (!billsLabel) {
    label = GmailApp.createLabel(billsLabel);
}
thread.addLabel(billsLabel);
thread.moveToArchive();
```

You can achieve this by first adding a label to the thread.
Then Archiving the thread this will move the email thread to the custom label. The first time I tried this I thought it didn't work. But once I refreshed the inbox and the custom label, I could see it worked.